# Check to see if child object exists in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I am building an object.  Inside a loop I need to check to see if the root object already contains a child object, and if not, I need to add it.

```
childObjectName = this.name.split('.')[1];
```

Now, how do I check to see if my root object, `myObject` already contains a child by the name of whatever is contained in `childObjectName`?

**EDIT:**

I think perhaps my OP wasn't very clear. Sorry about that.

Let's say `childObjectName` ends up having a value of "ThisName".  Now, I want to check and see if `myObject` already contains a child object called "ThisName".  And as this is in a loop, I need to be able to check for ANY name.

I hope that makes more sense?

**EDIT 2:**

```
{  
   "myObject":{  
      "CampaignType":{  
         "Exclusive":25,
         "Shared":6
      }
   }
}
```

Ok, now, let's say the var `childObjectName` is equal to "CampaignType".  In this case, I need to get TRUE when looing to see if `myObject` contains `childObjectName`.

But, let's say `childObjectName` is equal to "FooBar". In that case, I would need to get FALSE.

Comment: If by child you mean property, then `childObjectName in rootObject`. Or to be more precise `if (rootObject[childObjectName] === this)`.

Comment: The way you're describing your objects is a bit confused. Can you provide a sample JSON object to show the structure you're referring to?

Comment: sure. One second...

Comment: second edit added

Comment: Deleted my answer which your second edit nixed. Agalo's answer is almost correct, see my comment on it. I'd use it or Alex K's.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this. If a property doesn't exist in the object it returns `undefined`. So, you basically needs to check if the Property exists on the object or not.

```
if(! myObject[childObjectName])
{
  myObject.childObjectName = this.name.split('.')[1];
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that check inside myObject for a child object called "childObjectName" in stead of for a child object called whatever value is inside "childObjectName"?

Comment: You cannot use the dot accessor with a variable. Use brackets.

Comment: You can use the dot accessor with a property name,

Comment: @JaredSmith actually you can. Both dot accessing and key/value type bracket accessing work

Comment: @Casey - Do you need to check the *value* of the child Object Property or the Property Itself.

Comment: @Agalo only if `childObjectName` is hard-coded. But you can't stuff the result of a function call into it and have it work with the dot accessor.

Comment: for now, just checking to see if the child object exists.  See the edit to my OP.  Thanks!

Comment: @m_callens um, no, JavaScript doesn't work like that. If your accessor is a variable, you have to use square brackets.

Comment: @JaredSmith please run this and tell me how it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/pqdxw5g2/

Comment: @m_callens you. are. using. hard. coded. property. names. Tell me how you'd do it with the result of `String.prototype.split` as an accessor. For the third time now, if you have a string value in a variable, and you want to use that string value as a property lookup, you have to use square brackets. Period.

Comment: Careful: this won't work if `myObject[childObjectName]` is a falsy value. You'll end up overwriting the property, even though it does exist!

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty). It's compatible with all browsers, and it works even when the property has a falsy value, such as `null`, `false`, etc.

```js
var myObject = {
  propOne: "hello world",
  propTwo: false,
  CampaignType: {
    "Exclusive": 25,
    "Shared": 6
  }
};

checkForPropertyName("prop" + "One");
checkForPropertyName("propTwo");
checkForPropertyName("propThree");
checkForPropertyName("CampaignType");

function checkForPropertyName(childObjectName) {
  if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(childObjectName)) {
    console.log('myObject has property "' + childObjectName + '"');
  } else {
    console.log('myObject does NOT have property "' + childObjectName + '"');
  }
}
```

Comment: testing this now!

Answer (score 0):

```
childObjectName = childObjectName || this.name.split('.')[1];
```

If the property exists (and its value is truthy) its value will not change, otherwise it will be given a value. This can be applied to properties of root.

Note that this may not work if the property exists and it has a falsy value.

**Update for edit:**
If you need to to this for an arbitrary property and your code runs at the root level, then use **this** to refer to root:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this); // Now you have an array of properties set on root.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var childObjectName = this.name.split('.')[1];
if(myobject[childobjectName]){
   //the child object is present
 }else{
 //the child object is not present
 }
```

Comment: why do you think that @jared?

Comment: Other than using the correct access operator (a mistake I already pointed out in a comment) how is this different from Agalo's answer?

Comment: That is a wrong answer. *childObjectName* is a variable if you have not noticed!!. you can never do myobject.a_variable and access the value for the key

Comment: Yes, and I went to great lengths to point that out in the comments. So your answer provides what additional value?

Comment: Do you think I was waiting to see your comment when I was answering the question?

Comment: The fact is if it is a right answer or not. you cannot down vote to a right answer and make people confused.

Comment: I wrote that comment 11 minutes before you posted your (plagarized) answer. Conversation over, DV stands. Unless you want me to flag it for mod attention.

Comment: May be you do not know Once you open the answer box then you need to reload to see the other answers. I might have been doing something else after opening the answer box. I have enough knowledge of JS for not copying answer.

Comment: I do not care about your DV. There are people who needs good answer. I need there vote. And I do not want anything. If you want to flag it its your call.